# Import XCTest in to existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I added a new target as a Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle, named the directory "MyAppTests", and the actual framework is not active-- it is highlighted red

[image]

When I add the framework by the 'link binary with libraries' in the 'build phases' tab technique, a new Framework is added, instead of updating the one that was created with adding the target.

[image]

When I go to run the code, I then run in to all sorts of troubles, ranging from linking errors to other frameworks not being recognized.

How can I activate the XCTest.framework that was generated when I added target? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XCTest.framework is the bundle that Xcode uses to enable

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
```

To add test cases to an existing project select the target, right click > file > new > objective c test case class.  Then in your build phases you can add the XCTest.Framework.  Make sure you check the add to target boxes when creating the test case.

Comment: Yea, I was looking at the entire thing in the wrong way-- trying to import XCTest in to my controllers. Thanks for your help!