# app not compiling after change name of project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I changed the name of Xcode project and now the app not compiling.
The error is : "**XCTest/XCTest.h file not found**".
I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the framework search path in your code. Refer this [XCTest/XCTest.h not found on old projects built in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275470/xctest-xctest-h-not-found-on-old-projects-built-in-xcode-6)

*EDIT:-*

If you are using storyboard, select each of the view controller and check at the Storyboard ID field . Also make sure that none of the Storyboard ID fields should be blank.

Comment: Thanks now is compiling but crash "scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points"

Comment: Are you using storeyboard??

Comment: Yes I tried to start a new project but still this error