# IOS/Xcode: 'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found Error when loading older library

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I am trying to include a library called [Teacharts](https://github.com/xhacker/TEAChart) in my project, however, the app will not build due to an XCTest/XCTest.h error.

Currently the XCTest framework is not in the project.  When I added it to the project, the project would not build due to an error 'Framework not found XCTest'

According to some [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275470/xctest-xctest-h-not-found-on-old-projects-built-in-xcode-6) and elsewhere, Xcode seems to have moved this framework to a different place than it was in earlier versions.  Or perhaps this library is looking for it in the wrong path...This is very foreign to me and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Note: I am not using Cocoapods.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this error?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.