# fatal error: 'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild

I am trying to build a swift ios app via the command line for integration tests and I am getting the error in the title. This is a command im running in `ci`: `xcodebuild -workspace project.xcworkspace -scheme project -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator12.4 -derivedDataPath ./build clean build` so I need to have a fix that uses the command line or can be committed in the project so that it builds every time.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24651704/1805608

Comment: @Harish but how can i accomplish this via command line. I can't make this change manually all the time

Comment: okay...then you have to update your pod file like answered here..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078857/1244403

Comment: @Harish thanks man ill give that a shot!

Comment: cool..let me know if that works!!

Comment: @Harish it didn't work with those changes, I got a different error. I deleted those files that import that because we aren't unit testing this library at this time. Got my build to succeed

Comment: Delete your XCTest and re add if it does not work share your build logs